# Efficiency on query. Case vs INNER JOIN on temporalTable

Tags: performance, t-sql

What of this is better in terms of performance?

1. Using a temp table

   ```
   CREATE TABLE #sex (idReg INT, character NVARCHAR(1))
   INSERT INTO #sex
   SELECT 1, 'M'
   UNION
   SELECT 2, 'F' 

   SELECT p.name, s.character as sexChar
   FROM tbl_person p INNER JOIN #sex s ON p.sex=s.idReg
   ```
2. Using a CASE

   ```
   SELECT p.name,
   (case when sex=1 THEN 'M'
   when sex=2 THEN 'F'
   END) as sexChar
   FROM tbl_person p
   ```

(In the real case, there would be like 10 options instead just the M/F of the example)

Comment: I'd recommend that you check the query execution plan for both. Chances are you won't find cost difference between the two. Regardless, I'd recommend that you place a composite index on tbl_person.name and tbl_person.sex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one using the case statement is faster: Query cost is 12% relative to the batch, where the first one has Query cost of 88%